# LINQ composition - generates a weird FROM clause

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did the following linq to sql query generate a subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903036/why-did-the-following-linq-to-sql-query-generate-a-subquery)

I have a qs. for you LINQ gurus...

I am using LINQ in a composable way and the SQL being generated is a bit complex and of the form:

```
SELECT xxx FROM
(
   SELECT yyy from myTable1, myTable2
   WHERE foo == bar
) AS t7
WHERE t7.column == value.
```

The LINQ statement is formed by combining a few IQueryable types, whereby the SELECT part is in a method that returns an IQuerable and then I tack on some conditions elsewhere.

I know it is in the way I compose the LINQ that I need to tweak, but I want to finally execute SQL:

```
SELECT xxx FROM myTable1, myTable2
   WHERE foo == bar
and t7.column == value.
```

So, basically the nested FROM clause goes away.

This seems to be a standard problem, and I can provide more details of my LINQ statements, if needed.

Comment: Why does it matter?  If the performance and accuracy is the same, you shouldn't care that it's doing that...it's kinda the point of the abstraction.

Comment: Why do you care about what the query looks like?

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the linq statements involved...

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903036/why-did-the-following-linq-to-sql-query-generate-a-subquery

Comment: @TFD: You're exactly right. A more complete explanation is included on the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the SQL generated by LINQ to SQL use something like the [IQToolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/IQToolkit) and generate the SQL you do want.